# Is ggplot map spatial raster/grid so slow while using coord_map to convert projection?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The raster data contianing projection `wgs84` whose coordinates is lon/lat degree. If I want to map local area meeting suitable projection such as `albers`. main code as follows:

```
ras <- raster('r2008-03.tif')
ras_mtx <- rasterToPoints(ras_aea)
ras_df <- as.data.frame(ras_mtx)
colnames(ras_df) <- c('lon','lat','val')

basemap <- ggplot(data=ras_df,aes(x=lon,y=lat,fill=val))+
           geom_tile()+
           borders('world',xlim=range(ras_df$lon),ylim=range(ras_df$lat),
                colour='black')+ 
           coord_map(projection='albers',lat0=25,lat1=47)
```

[image]
It takes a long time (>10min) on mapping a small raster (260*400 resolution). The step `coord_map` for tranforming each grid point is slow. I think the input data.frame of `ggplot` reduce the efficiency of projection transform.
Why not use  matrix to mapping grid like `python` `basemap`?

So I convert raster projection firstly ,then map it. Now the xy coordinate unit is meter. How to convert the xy to lon/lat degree is another problem?

```
ras_aea <- projectRaster(ras,crs='+proj=aea +lat_1=25 +lat_2=47 +datum=WGS84')
ras_mtx <- rasterToPoints(ras_aea)
ras_df <- as.data.frame(ras_mtx)
colnames(ras_df) <- c('lon','lat','val')

bm <- ggplot(data=ras_df,aes(x=lon,y=lat,fill=val))+
      geom_raster()
```

[image]

First comment @Z.Lin has illuminated that the `coord_map` is actully slow rather than code error.  Therefore I should tranform raster projection before mapping. So my purpose is that change the geographic xy coordinate label(unit meter) to lon/lat (as upper fig).

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it about whether `coord_map` is slow? (If so, yes, the help file acknowledges "Map projections do not, in general, preserve straight lines, so this requires considerable computation.") Or is it about how to convert x/y to lon/lat? If the latter, can you post an illustration of your desired outcome?

Comment: For your explaination，I think the mapping method of latter question is  better. @Z.Lin